# How to disable form control but keep value

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form. On edit I want a control disabled.

The below works:

```
   this.myForm.controls['analysis_horizon'].disable();
```

However, the key analysis_horizon is no longer in my myForm.value hash.

How do I disable a field with a reactive form but keeping the value in the form values hash?

I tried [disabled]= but I get the below:

```
It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
      when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

      Example: 
      form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
      });
```

I load data from my database on edit into the form controls but I need one field to not be allowed to change.

Comment: it tells you to use disabled attribute directly in HTML, rather than using it with formcontrol.

Comment: Given that it's not changing, you could put it back into the value yourself for whatever is consuming it, with `Object.assign` or something.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but, why not do like the message suggests: `yourFormControl: new FormControl({value: yourPresetValue, disabled: true})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 disabled controls do not get included in the form.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148102/angular-2-disabled-controls-do-not-get-included-in-the-form-value)

Comment: I know this is old now, but reactive forms has another method that's called form.getRawValue() that would do this for you I cant say it works 100% of the time but it works when you use any of the setValue or patch Value methods

Comment: Angular 11 getRawValue() doesn't include disabled controls even if using patchvalue.

Answer (score 159):

You could use **getRawValue()** instead of the **value** property. According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html):

> The aggregate value of the FormGroup, including any disabled controls.
>
> If you'd like to include all values regardless of disabled status, use
>   this method. Otherwise, the *value* property is the best way to get the
>   value of the group.

```
this.myForm.getRawValue()
```

Answer (score 13):

My solution is using [attr.disabled]:

```
<select formControlName="foo"
  [attr.disabled]="disabled == true ? true : null"> 
</select>
```

Assuming you have a disabled property in your component. 
You have to retun null not false to enable the input.

Comment: Eventhough no warning is raised by Angular in this case, it still makes the application vulnerable to 'changed after checked' errors.

Comment: Aside from the `changed after checked` error, this is the only solution working for my case. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

Here is another option if you don't want to use getRawValue which changes the normal way of getting the value from forms. More reasons why I like readonly better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/1678151.

My solution also shows how to fill a form control.

component.ts

```
fillForm(data: any){
 if (data != null && data.firstName){
   this.form.patchValue({
     firstName: data.firstName
   })    
   this.firstNameIsReadOnly = true;
 }
```

template.html

```
<input formControlName="firstName" [readonly]='firstNameIsReadOnly'>
```

styles.scss

```
input[readonly] {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.38);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try add `onlySelf: true` inside method disable:

```
this.myForm.controls['analysis_horizon'].disable({onlySelf: true});
```

Comment: Welcome Vasyl! Can you please enclose your code with code tags?

Comment: This doesn't get expected effect. It also disables control from form.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this problem whilst trying to implement the Angular Material Datepicker with a reactive form - I wanted the input to be disabled so only the picker can set the date, however Angular shouts at you when you use the `disabled` attribute in the template, and then removes the value from the form when you do it in the component form group code.

The solution I came up with is to use CSS to prevent interaction with the input:

```css
.disable-pointer-events {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input
  class="disable-pointer-events"
  formControlName="yourControlName"
/>
```

Comment: This is an excellent option when you want to disable value changes but dont want to truly disable the control!

Answer (score 2):

To handle that elegantly without losing the value of the **formControl** is to use

```
[readonly]= condition ? true : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the solution to this problem I found another elegant aprouch changing the attribute again in the onSubmit function.

```
onSubmit() {
console.log('Before', this.myForm.value);

 this.myForm.controls['analysis_horizon'].enable();  // if edit

console.log('After', this.myForm.value);
```

}

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following approach (don't pay attention to custom controls - *Material* controls will also go, **fb** is a `FormBuilder` *DI*):

Code I use:

```
          this.addressTypeForm = this.fb.group({
            id: [null],
            ...
          });
          this.addressTypeForm.patchValue(this.selectedAddressType); //or patch only specific fields
```

`selectedAddressType` contains the data read from some external source and is supposed to be "read-only". Then specific data is copied into form via `patchValue`. If I don't want to let something be changed - e.g. `id` - I just output the read-only source data instead of the form.

Markup I use:

```
          <ng-container
            *ngIf="isNewAddressType; then addAddressTypeSelection; else editAddressTypeLabel"
          ></ng-container>
          <ng-template #addAddressTypeSelection>
            <bc-text
              [label]="'::AddressManagement:Id' | abpLocalization"
              [error]="abxForm.get('id').invalid && abxForm.get('id').touched"
              formControlName="id"
            ></bc-text>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #editAddressTypeLabel>
            <bc-text
              *ngIf="selectedAddressType"
              [label]="'::AddressManagement:Id' | abpLocalization"
              [disabled]="true"
              [value]="selectedAddressType.id"
            ></bc-text>
          </ng-template>
```

If you eventually are going to save the data from your form - which is logical - you don't want to disable its specific controls, because in this case you will loose their values. For instance, if you have `id` control disabled from the start (or disable it in other way dynamically):

```
          this.addressTypeForm = this.fb.group({
            id: [{ value: 111, disabled: true }],
            ...
          })
```

it will be displayed disabled here automatically:

```
            <bc-text
              [label]="'::AddressManagement:Id' | abpLocalization"
              [error]="abxForm.get('id').invalid && abxForm.get('id').touched"
              formControlName="id"
            ></bc-text>
```

But while saving such form, you will loose `id` value.

I usually disable and enable a whole form. But never - a specific form control (unless I intentionally want to "loose" its value, but I've never had such cases).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable a form control in Angular but keep its value intact, you'll need to handle the disabling separately from modifying the control's value. The disable() method in Angular's Reactive Forms disables the control and sets its value to null, which is likely what's causing the issue you mentioned earlier.

To disable the control without modifying its value, you can create a custom method to achieve this. Here's how you can do it:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-form',
  templateUrl: './my-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-form.component.css']
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      recommendation: [{value: 'initial value', disabled: false}] // Initialize the form control with a default value and disabled state
    });
  }

  disableRecommendation() {
    this.form.get("recommendation").disable({onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false}); // Disable the recommendation field without changing its value
  }
}
```

In this example, when the disableRecommendation() method is called, it disables the "recommendation" field using the disable() method with options {onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false}. This disables only the control itself without affecting its value or emitting any change events.

By passing **{onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false}**, you ensure that only the current control is disabled (onlySelf: true) and no change events are emitted (emitEvent: false), preserving the control's value.