# property on form control gets dropped (reactive form)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this model:

```
export class PlantArea {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public code?: string,
    public name?: string,
    public plantId?: number,
    public plant?: Plant,
    public company?: Company
  ) {}
}
```

And I have set up this form:

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(this.formData.id),
    code: new FormControl(this.formData.code, [Validators.required]),
    name: new FormControl(this.formData.name, [Validators.required]),
    company: new FormControl(this.formData.company, [Validators.required]),
    plant: new FormControl(this.formData.plant, [Validators.required]),
  });
```

I have a grid, where I have an edit button. Clicking on it shows the edit form, sets an input property, which binds the chosen entity to the form via `this.form.reset(entity)`:

```
@Input() set model(entity: T) {
    console.log(entity);
    this.form.reset(entity);
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.active = entity !== undefined;
    this.editMode = entity?.id ? true : false;
  }
```

The issue is, that by reseting the form values, the `plant` property gets dropped and the appr. control value isn't set. If I log the entity, the `plant` property is there, but if I log the form value, the `plant` property is gone:

[image]

Why is this? I can't figure out. There is a `plant` control on the form, so, it should bind the value to this, right?

Comment: What is structure of `Plant`?  This -> `plant: new FormControl(this.formData.plant, [Validators.required]),` should be FormGroup of `id` and `code`. If you set it as FormControl to set value it will expect like `plant:15`

Comment: I dont' think, it should be a FormGroup, because the same works for the `company` and this isn't a FormGroup. The `plant` is btw a simple object with `id` and `code` as you can see on the screenshot. The control on the form waits for an object value and not for a plain simly value.

Comment: How do you edit the `plant` and `company` fields in the form? Can you share the code? It will be easy to help if you provide in on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that was a false alarm. I have disabled the plant control initially and that's why the `form.value` hasn't the `plant` property.

See also this: [disabled control do not ged included in the form value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148102/angular-2-disabled-controls-do-not-get-included-in-the-form-value)